# Limit on number of nested IF statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, functions

Is there a technical reason when T SQL gives this error?

> Msg 191
> Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

My scenario is a function with several nested IFs with ELSEs :

```
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
```

Changing it to the following statement doesn't raise any error:

```
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END
```

Comment: It's just a curiosity. An old function that I am re-engineering had those statements.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this Microsoft Docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/if-else-transact-sql#remarks), nesting of `IF` statements is dependent on available memory.

On my test workstation, I was able to write and execute this, which is 189 levels deep:

```
declare @teste int;
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
IF (1=2) BEGIN SET @teste = 1 END ELSE
print 1
```

189 levels of nesting seems pretty bizarre to me, but then this *is* a bizarro world, lately.